# Random Number to String Doesn't Give Me Only The Random Number

Tags: java, android

been having a rough time with this and don't know why it's not working. Searched around, but couldn't find anything - would appreciate some help.

I'm trying to create a path for an image taken with camera on android however it is giving me:

```
/mnt/sdcard/java.util.Random@somerandomnumber.jpg
```

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to only get the random number without the java.util.Random. Thanks!

My code is as follows:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

String newimagename = String.valueOf(randomGenerator)+".jpg";

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + newimagename);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the value of `nextInt`. You're printing the location of the random number generator's state data itself.

Do:

```
int rNum=randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

String newimagename =Integer.toString(rNum)+".jpg";
```

You should also know that with such a low limit you'll run into collisions of filenames.